# user-defined functions and "pattern" being returned

Tags: pattern-matching, variable-definitions

I define a function as

```
f[J_] := Exp[J^2/2\[Mu]]
```

but when I try to taylor expand as

```
k[J_] = Series[f[J] ,{J,0,2}]
```

I'm getting this ghastly expression returned
[image]

I'm a mathematica newbie so I'm at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm getting something different—maybe try evaluating `Clear[f, k, \[Mu]]` and re-evaluating your expressions? what version are you on?

Comment: (also just a possible gotcha: `J^2/2\[Mu]` parses as `\[Mu] * J^2 / 2` without parentheses, not sure if this is what you intended!)

Comment: use `k[J_] :=` instead of `k[J_] =`

Comment: @JasonB. oops thanks I actually typoed this here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped. I think I might've defined something erroneously and it kept propagating beyond.

```
Clear[f, k, \[Mu]]
```

fixed it